# How would I read this "XML" type?

Tags: vb.net

This is the response (XML) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root response="True">
<movie 
title="Taken 3" 
year="2015" 
rated="PG-13"
released="09 Jan 2015" 
runtime="109 min" 
genre="Action, Crime, Thriller" 
director="Olivier Megaton" 
writer="Luc Besson, Robert Mark Kamen" 
actors="Liam Neeson, Maggie Grace, Famke Janssen, Forest Whitaker" 
plot="Liam Neeson returns as ex-covert operative Bryan Mills, whose long awaited reconciliation with his ex-wife is tragically cut short when she is brutally murdered. Consumed with rage, and framed for the crime, he goes on the run to evade the relentless pursuit of the CIA, FBI and the police. For one last time, Mills must use his 'particular set of skills,' to track down the real killers, exact his unique brand of justice, and protect the only thing that matters to him now - his daughter." 
language="English" 
country="France" 
awards="N/A" 
poster="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNjM5MDU3NTY0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTk2ODU2MzE@._V1_SX300.jpg" 
metascore="N/A" 
imdbRating="8.2" 
imdbVotes="1,159" 
imdbID="tt2446042" 
type="movie"
/>
</root>
```

How would I get data out of this type of XML? Like say I wanted to get "title" and imdbRating out of this data, which way should I go?

this is the code I have but it doesn't really work ...

```
Dim xml = XDocument.Load("config.xml") 
MsgBox(xml.<root>.<movie>.<title>.value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML to read the `XDocument` type.

First, add these imports to the top of your file:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
```

Then you can use methods `Element` and `Attribute` to get to the element that you need:

```
Dim xml = XDocument.Load("config.xml") 
MsgBox(xml.Element("root").Element("movie").Attribute("title").Value)
```

You can find additional information about [LINQ to XML in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387098.aspx)